# similar to second borell cantelli lemma

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of events in a probability space $(X,F,P)$ such that $P(A_n)<1$ for all $n$ , $ P(\bigcup A_n)=1$ , and $A_n$ are independent. Prove that $P(A_n i.o)=1$

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, let it be clear that all we have to do is show that:

[image]

Then, by the 2nd Borel-Cantelli Lemma and the independence of the sequence of events, we have the result. Let's begin:

[image]

Because of the independence:

[image]

The two previous equations give us:

[image]

At this point, you have to be familiar with infinite product of sequences. If you are not, then let me know so i can inform you, or google some information about it. There is a statement, which i found in a complex analysis textbook, that makes this problem a lot easier:

Corollary:
Let [image] be a sequence of real numbers, such that [image]. Then:

[image]

which (since all the terms are non-negative) is the same as this:

[image]

Now, we apply the result above for: [image]

We are able to do this because we know that: [image]

So, from the corollary, we have:

[image]

and finally, because of the above, from the 2nd Borel-Cantelli Lemma, we get:

[image]